# Can't create/write to file '/data2/mysql/c:/users/john.smith/documents/table_name.csv' (Errcode: 2)

Tags: mysql

I'd like to export data from my tables, but the request is appending '/data2/mysql/' at the front of my desired file path and I'm assuming this is causing issues. I don't know how to change or remove it.

The log messages claims to succeed when I replace / with \ but the file is not there in my documents where I specified.

I have this script taken from the MySQL tutorial:

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table_name
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/john.smith/Documents/table_name.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

This is the message that gets back to me:

Can't create/write to file '/data2/mysql/C:/Users/john.smith/Documents/table_name.csv' (Errcode: 2)

Update: When I do this: `C:\\Users\\john.smith\\Documents\\table_name.csv` the message log I receive says it succeeded, but the file does not end up at that location; doing this a second time prompts me a message that says the file already exists.

Comment: An alternative route is to manually export the data from MySQL Workbench if you have it.  Right click your table, Table Data Export Wizard and input your information.

Comment: I'm using Toad for MySQL. I should've specified that--my bad. They have an export option as well, but eventually I'd like to be able to put this on a routine import-export schedule and it seems at a glance that Toad's freeware doesn't have such an option.

Comment: Well MySQL Workbench is free if you're not tied to Toad.  I believe though you should also be to use the command line to do a [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-mysqldump.html) you can dump your entire databse or just a table.

Comment: What you get if you run this query: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';

Comment: @PeterHe there's no value for that variable name.

Comment: Can you post your my.cnf? seems mysql does not have permission to access the specified folder.

Comment: where do I find that file? is it located in C:\? If it's a permissions issue that narrows my issue a little bit...I think.